# Entity Framework Migrations history table

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.5

Is it possible to change the name of the history table that the migration framework uses?

I found this: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Migrations%20History%20Table%20Customization

but I cannot derive the HistoryContext on version 4.5 of the .Net framework.

Could someone provide an example if possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`HistoryContext` is still available to derive from. It is in the following namespace:

`System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History`

It is contained in the EntityFramework assembly. I can see that this is true for EntityFramwork 6. Perhaps you are using an older version? Ensure you've updated the NuGet package.